# How to spyOn controller's function that's invoked by a link clicked from UI?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I was trying to verify a function is called after clicking a link.  The click is invoked with jQuery in Jasmine test, but it looks like the scope is not the same as the controller's in the test. How can I make the test work in this case? The problematic code can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/yqKme59WD9isrZTCutKB?p=preview.

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
  var $scope;
  var ctrl;

  //you need to indicate your module in a test
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl as mc', {
      $scope: $scope
    });

    spyOn(ctrl, 'loadData').and.callThrough();
  }));

  it('should call load data', function() {
    ctrl.loadData();
    console.log("1:" + ctrl.name);
    expect(ctrl.loadData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should call load data after link cliked', function() {
    $('#change-name')[0].click(); 
    console.log("2:" + ctrl.name);
    expect(ctrl.loadData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Templates really have nothing to do with controllers so I would just test the controller function directly by calling it. For your tests, pretend the template doesn't exist and just test the controller's API

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/4MsnnrWllcNdLBvqpKdr?p=preview

Comment: Is there a way to get hold of that controller or scope used by the template?  I just hope I can verify this sort of state changes caused by UI events.

Answer (score 2):

Usually are tests divided into unit test and end to end test.

In unit test you can test components, controllers, services,... You can test if controller calls his dependencies properly.

UI (clicks, filling inputs,...) mostly testing in browser - with selenium, or http://www.protractortest.org/#/ (in case Angular)

In your sample, you create an instance of the controller, but there is no template, no DOM (resp. only jasmine/test-runner DOM). So it will not work.

Comment: Thank you, my real test actually loads a template and $compile into DOM.  Your suggestion solved partial of the problem, but I am still facing an issue with $digest variables set in controller into the DOM. The previous example has been updated with the working code, and I will update the issue I am having later.